# Change Podman container IP address

Tags: centos, networking, proxy, container, podman

I installed a `mtproto` proxy image with `Podman`. When I run it I get the error message that the 443 port is already in use. Indeed `httpd` is using it. I have another IP address in the same server that is only used now for `sshd`. How to force the container to use this other IP?

```
# podman run -d -p443:443 --name=mtproto-proxy --restart=always -v proxy-config:/data telegrammessenger/proxy:latest

# podman image ls
REPOSITORY                         TAG         IMAGE ID      CREATED       SIZE
docker.io/library/hello-world      latest      feb5d9fea6a5  5 months ago  19.9 kB
docker.io/telegrammessenger/proxy  latest      8ce753bac6d9  1 years ago   145 MB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you publish a port using `-p 443:443` it will attempt to bind to all available interfaces. You can have it bind to a particular ip address by providing that address as the first parameter of the `-p` option:

```
podman run -d -p 192.168.2.20:443:443 ...
```